Equation in the book Recherches analytiques sur la théorie des nombres premiers by Charles-Jean de La Vallée Poussin
In the book Recherches analytiques sur la théorie des nombres premiers by Charles-Jean de La Vallée Poussin, in page 53, he writes:
$$\int_{1}^{y}dy\left[\frac{\sin(\beta\log y)}{y}\sum_{p<y}\log p\right]=\sum_{p<y}\log p \int_p^{y}\frac{\sin(\beta\log y)}{y}dy$$
I am fairly confident that this equality is false, a mistake coming from confusing $y$ integration variable and $y$ variable, my reasoning to obtain a true equation is:
Call for $t>1$
$$f(t):=\sum_{p<t}\log p$$
this is a simple step function, some values are:
$\\$
$f(2)=0$, $f(3)=\log 2$, $f(\pi)=\log2+\log 3$, $f(5)=f(4)=\log 2+\log 3$.
It is obvious that:
$$\int_{1}^{y}dt\left[\frac{\sin(\beta\log t)}{t}\sum_{p<t}\log p\right]=\int_{1}^{y}dt\frac{\sin(\beta\log t)}{t}f(t)$$
Using the basic properties of integration:
$$=\log 2\cdot\int_{2}^{3}dt\frac{\sin(\beta\log t)}{t}+\cdots+\log p_i\cdot\int_{p_i}^{p_{i+1}}dt\frac{\sin(\beta\log t)}{t}+\cdots+\log p_n\cdot\int_{p_n}^{y}dt\frac{\sin(\beta\log t)}{t}$$
$$=\sum_{i= 1}^{n-1}\log p_i\int_{p_i}^{p_{i+1}}dt\frac{\sin(\beta\log t)}{t}+\log p_n\int_{p_n}^{y}dt\frac{\sin(\beta\log t)}{t}$$
where $0<p_1<p_2<\cdots p_n<y$ is the sequence of all prime numbers $<y$.
I would think that this is the proper way of simplifying this integral, what I am asking is if my reasoning is right or wrong.
